# Git:Getting changes from another brach to mine where both are in active development and not merged to master yet

Tags: git, git-branch

### Scenario

I have a 2 branches, branch1 and branch2 from master.Active development going on both the branch and no merging is made to master as it can be bugsome.

My problem is that, i want some of the feature i have developed in branch1 on branch2.

Is there any elegent way to do this other than copying files from one another?

Comment: yes, you can use the git cherry-pick command to pick commits from one branch to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply individual commits from either branch by using the [cherry-pick command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).